# Android: Using search API to do equivalent of startActivityForResult

Tags: android

I have an activity that is started from the search api. I would like it to "return" some values to the activity that was running when the search was instigated, in a similar way to startActivityForResult, but I can't see how to do it. Any suggestions?

> Activity A -> (startActivity) ->
>   Activity B -> (Search) -> Activity C
>   -> (return) -> Activity B

At the moment I'm starting a new instance of activity B using the values. This works, but the activity stack is then not the way it should be. Ie, pressing back from B would go back via C, B, A, instead of just A.

Any suggestions on the way to do this?

Comment: I've just realized that the workaround that I report above won't work in my case: A -> B actually uses startActivityForResult, not startActivity, so I need to pass back the result from the original B, so I can't create a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a solution: to combine B and C. Instead of having a separate search handling activity, I can get B to handle the search and pop up a dialog with the results in it. It doesn't feel elegant, I'd much rather have the separate, but it's the best solution I could find. This is assuming, of course, that it works, but I can't currently see a reason for it not to (in my particular situation).

EDIT: Here's the code. EditLocation is A, GetLocationMap is B

https://github.com/spookypeanut/Wake-Me-At/tree/e0dde4153c375c20bec3d7201b4faac2300f5956

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to know how to do this too. The only kludge I can think of is to have public static variables in B to pass the result back in, and then have C call finish() after setting said variables, with B processing the results in the onResume() method.